# Any contraindication of using Stored Procedures performing SELECT, UPDATE, INSTERT

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I'm using one SP performing all CRUD operations
So, basically I'm executing same SP depending what action necesary:

eg

```
-- for select
exec USP_ORDER @MODE='S', @ORDER_DATE='2009/01/01'
-- for update
exec USP_ORDER @MODE='U', @other_params
-- for insert
exec USP_ORDER @MODE='I', @other_params
-- for delete
exec USP_ORDER @MODE='D', @ID=100
```

Thanks that I have only 1 SP per 1 Buisness Object which keeps my DB ordered.
But recently I experienced performance issues.
In light on that my **question**:
Is this approach correct? Can it has influence on performance / proper exec. plan?

Answer (score 2):

It can have performance implications due to possible caching the 'wrong' query plan. Check out the topics ['parameter sniffing'](http://blogs.msdn.com/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx) and [query plan caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx).

EDIT: In response to John's comment, you could also have your top level SP decide which CRUD SP to call, then each would get its own cached query plan.

Comment: Hi Mitch, I thought in SQL 2005 and above, each batch/satement within a stored procedure had it's own execution plan? This is to aide recompilation so that only a specific step would recompile when necessary rather than the whole procedure?.....

Comment: So surely parameter sniffing would be a potential problem for all stored procedures and not just those with multiple types of crud operation?

Comment: @John Sansom: that is correct. The poster implies his has one SP performing all actions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more a coding/design preference question.

Personally, I am big fan of keeping things simple and for this reason I would suggest you break out your operations into separate stored procedures.

This will be more transparent and also aide any performance tuning you may have to do in future, i.e. if your update procedure/logic is performing slowly, you can immediately isolate it as the cause whereas if the logic is part of a much larger procedure with varying CRUD operations, the root cause of the issue will not be quite so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also fan of simplification (if possible).

But the reason I've decided on that way: currently I have ~80 SPs If I divide all by function they serve (eg. USP_Sample_Insert, USP_Sample_Select1, USP_Sample_Select2, 
USP_Sample_Delete) I will have ~400 SPs!

Managing, navigating, updating, sync parameters between such huge amount if SP instances would be nightmare to me.

For me - only reasonable case to do it is performance....